# Add an image to the front matter of a jekyll post

Tags: image, types, jekyll, blogs, yaml-front-matter

When using jekyll how do you add an image to the datatype of the front matter, so it shows up with the title and date within the blogpost list.

Answer (score 8):

Try to put an image path in your front matter.

I mean, all your post like this one:

```
---
title: My post
description: My description
image: /img/folder/image.jpg
----

bla bla bla
```

Therefore, you can load an image for every single post. This is an example:

```
---
layout: default
--- 

{% for post in site.posts %}
<p><h1>{{ post.title }}</h1></p>
<img src="{{ post.image | prepend: site.baseurl }}" alt="{{ post.title }}" title="{{ post.title }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Will the result of this show up in the feed of blog posts, or only in the individual posts.

Comment: The first code is a front matter for a single post. And the second one, it is a simple example for a page that can be index or archived.

Comment: I understand that, however, I am looking for a solution to add an image to the title and date of the post where it appears in the list of blog posts, not adding an image to the post itself.

Comment: `{{ post.image | prepend: site.baseurl }}` really helped me fix my image URLs in front matters, thanks!